# SQL Server - updating distinct values

Tags: sql, sql-server, distinct

I have 3 columns of data:

- Column1 has duplicate values eg a a b b c c
- Column2 has all NULL values
- Column3 has other data that is not really important

I want to update Column2 with a value eh Hello but only for 1 instance of each value for column1.  Eg, a = Hello but the 2nd instance of Hello is NULL, same with b c and so on.

I can find the distinct value by using this:

```
select distinct Column1 
from TABLENAME
```

But when I try to update a different column it breaks. What is wrong (probably a lot!!) with this:

```
update TABLENAME 
set Column2 = 'Hello'
where (select distinct Column1 from TABLENAME)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use `ROW_NUMBER` window function make row number then only update with row number is 1.

```
update t1 
set Column2 = 'Hello'
FROM (
    select *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Column1 ORDER BY Column3) rn
    from TABLENAME
) t1
where rn = 1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9c3a7/1/0)**:

```
| Column1 | Column2 | Column3 |
|---------|---------|---------|
|       a |   Hello |       1 |
|       a |  (null) |       2 |
|       b |   Hello |       3 |
|       b |  (null) |       4 |
|       c |   Hello |       5 |
|       c |  (null) |       6 |
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it is your unique index, use Column 3.

```
UPDATE tablename SET column2 = 'Hello' WHERE column3 IN
(SELECT column3 from TableName GROUP BY column1)
```

Comment: Will it?  The group by will choose a column1 value within each subset of column1.  Thus, it will only update the a single row from each grouping of column 1.

Answer (score 0):

You could also update only the rows that have odd numbers in Column 3.

```
UPDATE tablename SET column2 = 'Hello' WHERE column3 % 2 != 0
```

Comment: I almost wrote this! However, I think that could cause issues if there would be more than two values per distinct value of column1

Comment: Are you able to create temp tables? 

select column1, max(column3) column3 into #temp1
from yourtable group by column1

update yourtable set column3 = 'Hello' where column3 in (select column3 from #temp1)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `CROSS APPLY` and `CTE (Common Table Expression)` to achieve this:

```
;with CTE AS
(SELECT t.Column1, t.Column2 
FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT Column1 
        FROM   TABLENAME) x 
       CROSS APPLY(SELECT TOP 1 *
                    FROM   TABLENAME 
                    WHERE  column1 = x.column1) t)
UPDTATE CTE
SET Column2 = 'Hello'

SELECT * FROM TABLENAME
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a window function as

```
UPDATE TT
SET Col = B
FROM
(
  SELECT Col, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Col ORDER BY Col) RN
  FROM T
)TT INNER JOIN
(
  VALUES (1, 'Hello'), (2, NULL)
) TVC (A, B)
ON TT.RN = TVC.A;
```

**Results:**

```
+-------+
|  Col  |
+-------+
| Hello |
| NULL  |
| Hello |
| NULL  |
| Hello |
| NULL  |
+-------+
```

Or using a `CASE` expression as:

```
UPDATE TT
SET Col = CASE WHEN RN = 1 THEN 'Hello' END
FROM
(
  SELECT Col, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Col ORDER BY Col) RN
  FROM T
)TT;
```

<kbd>**[Online Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=9eaa86adc152286c7f197fb3baeb35ad)**</kbd>